# I have done a autoload dump to rebuild my class map

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Installed Moltin Cart through composer, then added the Service Provider: `'Moltin\Cart\CartServiceProvider'` and added the aliases `'Cart' => 'Moltin\Cart\Facade'`.

Now i am getting the laravel 4 error :

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException Class 'Moltin\Cart\CartServiceProvider' not found.
```

I have done a autoload dump to rebuild my class map `composer dump-autoload` but still have the problem.

my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master",
         "moltin/cart": "dev-master"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"

}
```

my app.php here

```
<?php

return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Debug Mode
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
| stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
| application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
|
*/

'debug' => true,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
| the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
| your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
|
*/

'url' => 'http://localhost',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'UTC',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Locale Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
| by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
| to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
|
*/

'locale' => 'en',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
| to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
| will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
|
*/

'key' => 'Hb2cd1FUfJV6S0ApZAS9QSAQEFEiusUc',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Autoloaded Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
| request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
| this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
|
*/

'providers' => array(

    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\MigrationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\SeedServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
     'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider',
      'Moltin\Cart\CartServiceProvider'


),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Service Provider Manifest
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The service provider manifest is used by Laravel to lazy load service
| providers which are not needed for each request, as well to keep a
| list of all of the services. Here, you may set its storage spot.
|
*/

'manifest' => storage_path().'/meta',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => array(

    'App'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
    'Artisan'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
    'Auth'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
    'Blade'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
    'Cache'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
    'ClassLoader'     => 'Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader',
    'Config'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
    'Controller'      => 'Illuminate\Routing\Controller',
    'Cookie'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
    'Crypt'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
    'DB'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
    'Eloquent'        => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
    'Event'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
    'File'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
    'Form'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Form',
    'Hash'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
    'HTML'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\HTML',
    'Input'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
    'Lang'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
    'Log'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
    'Mail'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
    'Paginator'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator',
    'Password'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
    'Queue'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
    'Redirect'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
    'Redis'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
    'Request'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
    'Response'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
    'Route'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
    'Schema'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
    'Seeder'          => 'Illuminate\Database\Seeder',
    'Session'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
    'SSH'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\SSH',
    'Str'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Str',
    'URL'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
    'Validator'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
    'View'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',
     'Image'           => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image',
      'Cart'            => 'Moltin\Cart\Facade'
),
```

);

Comment: Can we see your app.php?

Comment: you can see above app.php?

Comment: please help me i post my app.php above

Comment: Have you confirmed that MoltinCart is in your vendor directory?

Comment: in my vendor directory there is moltin but not moltincart

Answer (score 0):

The package that you are requiring does not contain a class `Moltin\Cart\Facade` or `Moltin\Cart\CartServiceProvider`. This is because the package "moltin/cart" is a generic package that does not provide anything for integration with Laravel.

The package you are looking for is named "moltin/laravel-cart".

However, I'd advise against using it. The tests of the master branch of "moltin/cart" are currently failing, and there is no official, tagged release. The "moltin/laravel-cart" is awkwardly versioned (it seems they synced their versions with the target version one of Laravel), however they failed to notice that Laravel explicitly does NOT follow semantic versioning, so requiring `~5.0` as "moltin/laravel-cart" does will either install some 5.0 or 5.1 version, which will be incompatible.

Comment: i installed laravel 5.1 but i got errors,
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Application::d
etectEnvironment() must be an instance of Closure, array given,

Comment: my project i was created using laravel 4.1 how do i move to laravel 5.1and see clear mya project